update average price in stock when add new entry voucher
/articles(ID,Qte_stock,PU)/
/DETAILS_BON_ACHAT(ID,qte,prix,id_article)/
I want to update PU (price of product) in articles A table (items of stor) for each record in DETAILS_BON_ACHAT D table (
NOTE : the new PU must be calculated like this ( ((D.prixD.qte)+(A.PUA.Qte_stock))/(D.qte+A.Qte_stock))
I TRIED enter image description here
/*articles(ID,Qte_stock,PU)*/
/*DETAILS_BON_ACHAT(ID,qte,prix,id_article)*/
USE bitsclic_easy_erp;
UPDATE articles set PU=(
    SELECT ((D.prix*D.qte)+(A.PU*A.Qte_stock))/(D.qte+A.Qte_stock)
    FROM DETAILS_BON_ACHAT D 
    INNER JOIN articles A
    ON D.id_article = A.ID
    WHERE D.id_bon='1' 
    GROUP BY D.id_article
    );

i got error :Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'articles' for update in FROM clause

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@dockercompose please open included image you will understand my question

This question is similar to: MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'd consider a view instead - will always be up-to-date. (Copying data between tables too often leads to inconsistency.)
